# Simple_Salesforce Dynamic bulk query

Tags: python, simple-salesforce

Dynamically add an object to the bulk query job for Simple_Salesforce.

I'm not sure how to pass a variable to `sf.bulk."Object".query`.

I would like to be able to pass an object say "Account" to the definition and it does the bulk query `sf.bulk.Account.query("SOQL...")`

```
sf = Salesforce(username=sf_username, password=sf_password, security_token=sf_token)

def SOQL(table):
    qryResult = sf.bulk.`table`.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + table)

SOQL("Account")
```

I would like python to translate this to `sf.bulk.Account.query("SELECT Id FROM Account")`

Comment: This looks like a minimal example of what you're trying to do so, nice. But, might be able to help you more if you add a bit more info as to why you want to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can directly call `sf.bulk`'s [`__getattr__` method](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/bulk.py#L50):

```python
sf = Salesforce(username=sf_username, password=sf_password, security_token=sf_token)

def SOQL(table):
    return sf.bulk.__getattr__(table).query('SELECT Id FROM ' + table)

result = SOQL("Account")
```

I added a `return` cause I figured you'll want the result (I realize this is probably a minimal example but still).

#### Why this works:

Basically, behind the scenes, when you call `sf.bulk.Account`, python is calling `sf.bulk.__getattr__("Account")` for you. (that's a long story made short; [dig more into python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) and into the linked source code for more)

Comment: Why use the `__getattr__` method instead of [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)?